# Usage of 'gradlew' in Perl hang up

Tags: perl, android-gradle-plugin

I'm using perl script to invoke the gradlew batch file generated from Android Project.

There is chance that my whole build would get hang at calling 'gradlew clean' or 'gradlew assembleRelease'. When the problem happened, the log showed 'BUILD SUCCESSFUL
Total time: 31 seconds' something like that. While it never returned.

My script was like following ,

```
`gradlew clean -S --offline -Dorg.gradle.daemon.idletimeout=300000>> $resultsfile 2>&1`;
`echo gradlew clean done >> $resultsfile 2>&1;
```

How can I debug into this problem?

Comment: `$resultsfile` needs to be escaped properly, e.g.: `\Q$resultsfile\E`. There might be an [`$IFS`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Internal_field_separator)-separated word in it that might invoke an executable with the matching name (for instance, `read the docs.txt` might "call" the `read` command)

Comment: Thanks for Ruslan's answer. It sounds quite making sense. I'll try and observe on it